# SSO for Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, single-sign-on

I would like to know is there SDK available for Twitter Single-sign-on for android as Face Book developers have created Sdk 3.0.

I have googled it and found this uptill know that SSO for twitter is only available for iOS but not for android.

Need some help on this if any source/reference  available then please share it

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ???

Comment: Not really  got the solution